# Localization of SPView.Title

Tags: list-view, localization, spview

Has anybody had any experience with the localization of a View's Title?

I tried to change DisplayName of view in SharePoint Designer 2010, but it does not seem to work:

```
DisplayName="<%$Resources:Resources,ViewTitle%>"
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? Shouldn't the `DisplayName` property be set in the `schema.xml` file?

Answer (score 1):

You can't localize a value in SharePoint Designer.  This value is the localized version of the value.  To localize a value, you have 2 choices : Put this tag in the schema.xml of the list definition OR edit both of the display name by using the MUI of SharePoint 2010.  The MUI keeps track of the localized value user give.  So iy you put "My title" in the english interface of a certain view, and you put "Mon titre" in the french interface of the view, it will display "My title" in english, and "Mon titre" in the french one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the context of your question is. However, in general the Resources tag format is:

```
$Resources:FileName,ResourceKeyName;
```

The file must be placed in the Resources directory of the 12 or 14 hive.